# Python cx_oracle insert error

Tags: python, oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to insert records from `csv` into `oracle 11g` database using `python` script.

Primarily the application successfully insert some record, but later throws this exception Error  `<class 'cx_Oracle.DatabaseError'>` .

```
def orcl_proc(sql):
    # Open database connection
    db = cx_Oracle.connect('username/password@localhost/XE')
    # prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
    cursor = db.cursor()
    try:
        # Execute the SQL command
        cursor = cursor.execute(sql)
        # Commit your changes in the database
        db.commit()
    except cx_Oracle.DatabaseError as e:
        # Log error as appropriate
        error, = e.args
        print('Error.code =', error.code)
        print('Error.message =', error.message)
        print('Error.offset =', error.offset)
        # Rollback in case there is any error
        db.rollback()
    # disconnect from server
    db.close()
    #print('Closed')
```

Error:

```
<class 'cx_Oracle.DatabaseError'>
```

Out of 56,367 records the python application was only able to insert 180 records. Can any body help me please, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found the answer. Thanks to LittleFoot and Christopher Jones.
After removing the exception handler, I got `ORA-12516: TNS:listener could not find available handler with matching protocol stack`, I have to increase the database process and session.

```
alter system set processes=1000 scope=spfile;
alter system set sessions=2248 scope=spfile;
startup
```

and it worked. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Remove exception handler from your Python script. Let Oracle database propagate it and you'll know what exactly caused the error, seeing its Oracle error code and message text.

Then, if you aren't sure what these mean, come back here and post how Oracle responded.

Comment: After removing the error handler i get :=== cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-12516: TNS:listener could not find available handler with matching protocol stack

Comment: Just to make sure: you removed (or commented) **every** line between `db.commit()` and `db.close()`?

Comment: def orcl_proc1(sql):
        db = cx_Oracle.connect('EGIS_DATA/thisis4polaris@localhost/XE')
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor = cursor.execute(sql)
        db.commit()
        db.close()

Comment: I think for every insert, oracle is opening a new session, i don't know if the session can be closed

Comment: Aha, didn't see ORA-12516 (did you edit the comment? Doesn't really matter). Anyway: if possible (i.e. you have required privileges), try to modify the PROCESSES database parameter check its value (connect as SYS) with `show parameter processes`, then enlarge it. Perhaps you should ask your DBA to do it for you; otherwise, read this: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/initparams004.htm#i1124571

Answer (score 0):

An intermittent "ORA-12516: TNS:listener could not find available handler with matching protocol stack" is likely to when the rate of connections to the DB is higher than the DB is configured to cope with.  Try bumping the 'processes' parameter of the DB.  If you need help with that, see the section "Configuring the Database For Testing" in the free PDF http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/php/underground-php-oracle-manual-098250.html